# Abandon Clan Hall Quest

Tags: lineage-2-revolution

Is there a way to abandon the Clan Hall Quests manually?

I've tried holding the quest, but that brings up no option to cancel. There is no little X to tap on either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Clan Hall Quests expire every 7 days. There is no way to manually remove them. You will just have to wait until the quests expire before picking up new ones.